# Does Named pipe have corresponding device driver?

Tags: c, pipe, named-pipes

> Definition:
>   The device file is the **interface** between programs and the device driver. The **device driver** is in the kernel; the programs (applications) are in user space. The way a program can access the driver in the kernel is via the appropriate device special file.

Named pipe exist as a device special file in the file system.

My question:

I the case of named pipe, if it is a device special file, then(by definition) device file is an interface to some device driver in kernel space. Does corresponding *device driver* exist in kernel space?

Because, I do not see major/minor number below

```
$ ls -l MYFIFO
        prw-r--r--   1 root     root            0 Dec 14 22:15 MYFIFO|
```

Comment: @moooeeeep  Not relevant but already visited links. Infact the definition in my query is from those links. Check slide 32 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DrjQBL5FMU). In file types, Pipe is different from character/block device file. `ls -l MYFIFO` does not give major/minor number

Comment: The mere fact that the device type for a FIFO (named pipe) is different from a block device or character device doesn't mean that there isn't a device driver for it — at least, not if you interpret 'device driver' as 'code in the kernel that ensures the correct behaviour of the device being accessed'.  Regular files are different from block and character devices too, but there are definitely device drivers (and file system management code) in the kernel to make them work as expected.  Regular files don't expose major/minor numbers either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If there is a device driver for named pipe, then why don't I see the major/minor number on `ls -l MYFIFO`?

Comment: Because it isn't a device driver accessed via major/minor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  So, File types, "RegularFile/Directory/SymbolicLink" does not have corresponding device driver. File types, "Character/Block device file, Pipe and Socket" have corresponding device driver with device file as interface. Is that correct?

Comment: I already noted that regular files could be said to have device drivers — at least, they have code that handles the file type.  ditto sockets, doors, directories, symlinks, ...   In fact,when it comes down to it, all file types are handled by the kernel via code that handles that file type..  Computers don't handle physical paper files because no-one's worked out how to write a device driver for the job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127190/discussion-between-overexchange-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: A named pipe is not a device and therefore does not have a device driver. It probably has a *driver* component in the OS, but not a *device driver.*

Answer (score 1):

Lets define "kernel" as 2 categories of things - the "core services" (like physical memory management, scheduler, etc), and then "non-core services" (things that aren't always present, like device drivers, file systems, etc - e.g. like ext2 might not be present because you're using RieserFS instead). *Note that this is already limited to specific type of kernel (e.g. monolithic kernels and not micro-kernel).*

Lets define "device driver" as a piece of code intended sit between one abstraction (the kernel's device driver API, as determined by the OS/kernel designer) and another abstraction (the hardware interface provided by the corresponding device, as determined by hardware designer/manufacturer).

For almost all kernels, one of the "core services" is IPC (Inter-Process Communication) - some way for processes to communicate. For lots of kernels there are multiple different forms of IPC (shared memory, messages, signals, etc). Pipes are just another form of IPC.

Most pipes don't have a name - you just get some sort of opaque handle (e.g. a file descriptor). A named pipe is the same as a normal pipe; except that you associate a name to the pipe so that other processes can find the opaque handle from a "known" name.

Based on all of the above; named pipes do not have a device driver (and are a "core service" and therefore aren't even in the same category as device drivers).

However, "based on all of the above" means "based on my definitions that I made up". The real problem here is that there's no real consensus for how any of the terminology is defined. This is why good books (and good OS documentation) will explicitly define these things. This is also why about half of the people that read this answer will disagree (because they define things like "device driver" differently).

Comment: [Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node16.html#SECTION00731000000000000000) it says, named pipes exists as device files in filesystem. Does that not mean, there is corresponding device driver? or Is this device file just for IPC and nothing more than that?

Comment: @overexchange: It means that there is no corresponding device driver (and "device file" is just used to mark it as special in some way and doesn't imply there's a driver); and that there is a "named pipe driver"; and that whatever is on the other end of the named pipe is a "driver" (even if it's a user-space thing). It means all these mutually exclusive things at the same time (where someone who defines "device driver" like I do thinks one thing, and other people that define "device driver" in different ways think different things, and nobody is right/wrong because there's no consensus).

Answer (score 1):

There is a driver named "NPFS Driver" and its file is Npfs.sys

"NPFs stands for NPFS (Named Pipe Filesystem) Driver" -https://www.file.net/process/npfs.sys.html

And

npsvctrig.sys is the file for the driver named "Named pipe service triggers"

Both of these drivers are on my system, found using the software Serviwin, and it shows the drivers are 'Started'. For reference, there are other drivers that are stopped, so these two drivers must be in active use. No idea if this is what you're after.